# drupal form api call function

Tags: forms

I have a select box in my drupal form and i want to call a spesific php function whenever the select option is changed. How can i achieve this?

this is my code so far:

```
function langSelect_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['langSelect'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('English'), t('Norsk'),t('Samisk'))),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can go through [AJAX Forms in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/752056). It describes how you can use ajax in your form with examples

Comment: thanks, i was able to change content inside a div with the use of a ajax callback but can i do more advanced logic in that callback function as well or is it only ment for returning new output? for instance, i want to change the language of drupal when a user selects another languge in the select box.

Comment: check this module http://drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown